# What is useHistory instance of react-router-dom v5?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

As we know in v5 of `react-router-dom` we could use `useHistory` hook to get history object.
But if we have SSR and make our object one of `createMemoryHistory` and `createBrowserHistory` ways.

What instance will `useHistory` give us?

Answer (score 2):

`useHistory` is [really straightforward](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/hooks.js): it takes `history` from context.

So it depends how do you make your SSR. If you make it right(otherwise your app would not navigate regardless hooks used) `useHistory` takes *according* router(`useMemoryRouter`).

Other case when for some reason you have `<MemoryRouter>` and `<BrowserRouter>` at the same time(but different places). Then `useHistory` will return closest one in components' hierarchy.